# non-www to www mod rewrite rule getting caught buy later rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rules in place, tested with htaccess tester - they appear valid. However the non-www to www rule seems to get picked up by the final rule.

```
# Redirect non-www to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site-name.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site-name.com/$1 [R=301]

# SSL only please 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site-name.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Sections
RewriteRule ^sections/([^/]+)/ /section.php?slug=$1 [nc]

# Content managed pages 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages.php?slug=$1
```

Example:

```
https://site-name.com/sections/something/
```

Actually ends up at:

```
https://www.site-name.com/pages.php?slug=https://www.site-name.com/sections/something//something/
```

All other rules work as anticipated.

Comment: Make flags of first redirect rule to be: `[R=301,L,NE]` and test in a separate browser.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I will look up what the L and NE mean. Thank you.

Comment: _Aside:_ Consequently, you should also add the `L` flag to your 3rd (and 4th) rule. The _conditions_ in your last (4th) rule are in the wrong order. The 3rd _condition_ (that checks that the requested filename does not end in `.php`) should be 1st (otherwise it rather defeats the point of having it in the first place).

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite, I will re-jig the order of the last rule, I'd set about adding the L flag to the others. Thx again.